# How to speed up Python script iterating nested loop?

Tags: python, loops, search, iteration

I'm running a Python script which iterates two huge lists and finds the matching pairs.

However, it seems to take forever. How to speed up this script?

```
import sys
import random
import itertools

def main(args):
    target_num = int(999999999)
    num_list = range(1, target_num)
    rand_list = []
    hit_list = []

    for _ in itertools.repeat(None, target_num):
        rand_list.append(random.randint(1, target_num))

    for num in num_list:
        for rand_num in rand_list:
            if num == rand_num:
                print "hit"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Try not to use built-in names as variable names in your code, it has the potential to cause frustration. By this I am referring to your use of `list` as a variable name

Comment: @Smac89 I was in a hurry to write a question, and made a mistake. I modified the variable name.

Comment: Is that second nested loop supposed to be `read_list` or `rand_list`?

Comment: @Smac89 It is supposed to be rand_list. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Also consider a list comprehension (`rand_list = [random.randint(1, target_num) for _ in itertools.repeat(None, target_num)]`). They are more efficient than using for loops as you don’t need to load the append attribute off of the list and call it as a function.

Comment: Is there any reason to use `itertools.repeat` here rather than `range` (or `xrange`, since you're in Python 2)?

Comment: Have you considered Cython?

Comment: @Blckknght: `repeat` is actually faster, and given the values aren't being used, `range` provides no benefit but convenience. Mind you, convenience is nice; the perf benefit of `repeat` is small, not enough to make it worth the bother in 99.99% of cases, but when the index doesn't matter, may as well save the cost of producing it.

Comment: What is the purpose of this code?  The code you have provided will take forever (or at least, up to several years, given that it is 1E+17 comparisons), and minor improvements might reduce that a bit, but not by much, so this seems like a good opportunity to see if there is a better way to accomplish what you actually want to do rather than just try to improve your first attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use sets

```
import sys
import random
import itertools

def main(args):
    target_num = int(999999999)
    num_list = set(range(1, target_num))
    rand_list = []
    hit_list = []

    for _ in itertools.repeat(None, target_num):
        rand_list.append(random.randint(1, target_num))


    for num in rand_list:
        if num in num_list: # O(1)
            print "hit"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Using a set for the first list, means that checking if the item is in that list is now reduced to an O(1)

---

As I am writing this, I realise you can even do better. The [**range**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function in python 3 returns a sequence, so you need python 3 for this next part

```
import sys
import random
import itertools

def main(args):
    target_num = int(999999999)
    num_list = range(1, target_num) # this is a generator
    rand_list = []
    hit_list = []

    for _ in itertools.repeat(None, target_num):
        rand_list.append(random.randint(1, target_num))


    for num in rand_list:
        if num in num_list: # Stil O(1)
            print ("hit")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Even better, using range and do the checking within the first loop?

```
for _ in itertools.repeat(None, target_num):
    rand_num = random.randint(1, target_num)
    rand_list.append(rand_num)
    if rand_num in num_list:
        print ("hit")
```

Comment: `O(1)` membership testing is not a feature of `xrange`, it was only added to `range` in [Python 3.2 when they finally finished implementing the Sequence ABC for `range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range). `xrange` membership testing generates and tests values one at a time until it gets a hit. Also, neither `range` nor `xrange` are generators; they're more or less Sequence objects that can produce iterators, not iterators/generators themselves; if they were generators, iterating them once would exhaust them, but that's not how they behave.

Answer (score 1):

If using Python 2, use xrange(), which returns a generator-like object.

```
# requires Python 2
import random

target_num = 99 # 999999999 are too much items for testing

# target_num random numbers in range 1 .. target_num-1
random_numbers = set(random.randint(1, target_num) for _ in xrange(target_num)) 

hits = set()
for num in xrange(1, target_num):  # check for all numbers in range 1 .. target_num-1
    if num in random_numbers:   # num in set() is O(1)
        hits.add(num)

if len(random_numbers - hits) == 0:
     print "all random numbers are hits!"

# so:
for num in random_numbers:
    print num
# is the same result
```